# ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN When 2 of 3 DCs are down

Tags: active-directory, domain, domain-controller

I have 3 DCs on my domain, (2 on local office, 1 in Amazon AWS), and I would like to move to Amazon and cut off the 2 local DCs.

I have shut down the 2 local DCs, to test if the AmazonDC is working correctly, but then I receive "ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN" errors using nltest on Client computers, and I am no longer able to login to client computers with domain accounts.

I am not an expert, but I have tried the following:

- Replication works, check with "repadmin /showrepl"
- Client see all 3 DCs when using "nltest /dclist:mydomain.com"
- Secure Channel seems ok when checking with "nltest /sc_query:mydomain.com" and also with PowerShell "Test-ComputerSecureChannel -Server "amazonDC.mydomain.com"
- Firewall turned off, does not help
- All 5 FSMO roles are on one of the **local** DC (this could be the problem?)

I would appreciate any help, idea, or observation of what could be the problem here, or how should I properly move up to Amazon without the local office DCs, and how to test it before moving.

**Edit1**: Installing the DNS role on the Amazon DC did solve the problem, I no longer receive the "ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN" errors, although when I try to login, I now get an error "the remote computer that you are trying to connect to requires network level authentication", but I guess that's a different story. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have your two local DC's set as DNS servers for your clients. When either of them is online DNS lookups work fine, and you can see the AWS DC.

When both local DC's go offline your clients are left without functioning name resolution, and can no longer reach the AWS DC.

Set the secondary DNS server to the IP of the AWS DC for the duration of the test. If it works fine at that point, update your DHCP DNS configuration.

Comment: You are correct, the 2 offline DC is also a DNS, while on Amazon I have only a DC. Would it be a solution if I install the DNS role to Amazon too?

Comment: If the two DC's with DNS are down and the AWS DC does not have DNS then how do you expect domain clients to find the domain and the DC? Yes, you need to add DNS to the AWS DC and configure your clients to use it for DNS.

Comment: @joeqwerty I do have an external DNS service called DNSMadeEasy, which is configured as a primary DNS provider on the client computers (DNSMadeEasy nameserver IP). The clients are able to access websites, and name resolution works correctly, but only when the two DC is running, so yeah, something obviously not configured correcltly.

Comment: Active Directory uses DNS to discover domain controllers. You *should* use a DNS server integrated with AD as DNS server in a AD enviroment. Not doing so will lead to a huge mess. It doesn't *have* to be the DCs; it's fully possible to use `bind` with a stub zone for instance, or configure forwarders, or even configure AD to update a `bind` server. However, if you don't know how AD works, it's *recommended* to use the DC's as DNS server for the clients.